# Conda virtual environment not changing under Windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda

I have installed Anaconda 2.2.0 for Windows and created a virtual environment via:

```
> conda create -n my-env anaconda
```

The environment is sucessfully created and I see it in my list of envinronments (and indeed the directory is there in Anaconda\envs..)

```
> conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
my-env                   D:\Anaconda\envs\my-env
root                  *  D:\Anaconda
```

However, when running the activate.bat script to switch envinronment, although it appears to be successful the switch isn't actually made:

```
> activate.bat my-env
Activating environment "astropy-dev"...
> conda list -e
# conda environments:
#
my-env                   D:\Anaconda\envs\my-env
root                  *  D:\Anaconda
```

With the `*` indicating the active environment.

I have seen some issues with conda activate on Windows but haven't found this sepecific issue.

For further info: I am looking to copy the whole Anaconda package distribution and then install a dev version over one package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using Powershell, `activate` currently does not support it. You will need to modify your PATH manually, or else use the cmd shell.

Comment: Yep, works when using it in cmd shell. I had indeed tried in Powershell - couldn't see anywhere in the docs saying this didn't work though. I'm working under cygwin on Console where the behaviour in the original question is also seen, I'll just work around it for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `activate` from within a batch script? Then it should be `call activate my-env`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the .bat. It's just activate my-env.

Comment: Does omitting the ".bat" actually solve the problem though (and if so, why)? Or is it just a bit unnecessary but doesn't change anything (i.e. activate gets run whether you have it or not)?

Comment: Yes, what DavidW said. This makes no difference whatsoever - the same script is being called regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You command

```
activate astropy-dev
```

must be run from the D:\Anaconda directory. Then it should work.
To check, type:

```
conda info -e
```