# conda activate env not changing file directory

Tags: python, batch-file, environment-variables, virtualenv, anaconda

I can't write (and therefore install packages) to the `C:\Anaconda\envs\` folder, but even after changing the envs directories variable to point to a new path the `activate` command does not work.

[image]

Any suggestions? I looked at the activate.py script, but don't see an error message that matches mine or where to change the file path

Working in Windows-64. Not in powershell. Not sure how to manually edit my PATH. Already looked at [Conda virtual envinment not changing under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863720/conda-virtual-envinment-not-changing-under-windows) - similar issue

I also didn't have success with this similar post: [How to activate an Anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment)

The activate.bat file is what is generating the error at line 24, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Seems like the ANACONDA_ENVS is set in line 4, but I have no idea what ANACONDA_ENVS=%%~fi means

Comment: Have you tried a space after `activate my_root `?

Comment: I tried that solution, but no luck :(

Comment: This is strange.  Are you able to make a new test env, activate it and remove it?

Comment: conda does not know to look for an environment in c:\users\USERNAME\.conda\envs by default.  See my answer below.

Comment: I haven't been able to make a test env that activates at all. I have done this on other laptops where I can access the C drive, but this is beyond me. I think it has to do with the activate file not connecting to the envs directories variable or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a new path variable to your .condarc file (NOTE: this assumes `%USERPROFILE%` is your C:\Users\USERNAME directory used above)

```
conda config --prepend envs_dirs %USERPROFILE%/.conda/envs
```

Close and reopen CMD and try

```
activate my_root
```

Comment: I gave it a go (with an added ':' after conda config) but the environment still didn't activate. The error message implies it is still looking in the C:\Anaconda\envs folder

Answer (score 0):

Type:

```
activate C:\Users\N029810\.conda\envs\my_root
```

The prompt should change to:

```
(my_root)
```

Now, you should be able to install packages:

```
conda install <apackage>
```

Comment: still no luck,  'No environment named C:\Users\N0209810\.conda\envs\my_root exists in C:\Anaconda\envs\'

Comment: Can you re-install Anaconda as user, not as root/admin?

Comment: Its a work computer so unfortunately that's not an option

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I modified the header of the activate.bat copy from "my_root\Scripts" folder and added fixed path:

```
 for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%~dp0..\envs") do (
    set ANACONDA_ENVS=C:\Users\yourusername\.conda\envs
)
```

This means that I had to execute in the prompt

```
C:\Users\yourusername\.conda\envs\Scripts\activate my_root
```

specifying the full path.

Answer (score 0):

copying the activate.bat file fixed it for me